# Não consigo executar create-react-app

Tags: react, terminal, npm

Ao executar `npx create-react-app my-app` meu terminal não é concluído e ao final é criado a pasta dessa maneira:

```
└─ my-app
    ├─ node_modules
    ├─ package.json
    └─ yarn.lock
```

Já tentei `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` e depois novamente o `npx create-react-app my-app` mas não funcionou. Também já apaguei a pasta com esses arquivos várias vezes. Como posso fazer para dar certo?

---

Mensagem do terminal:

```
yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
**warning** react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
**warning** react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
**warning** react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
**warning** react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native 
has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
**warning** react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[2/4] Fetching packages...
**info** fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
**info** "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
**info** fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
**info** "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
**warning** "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 
3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 331 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.1
├─ react-dom@17.0.1
├─ react-scripts@4.0.1
└─ react@17.0.1
info All dependencies
└─ (várias dependências aqui)
Done in 509.92s.
```

Comment: Qual o erro? A mensagem não parece indicar que houve problema.

Comment: Ei, @LuizFelipe! Não são criados os arquivos necessários como a pasta public e a src. O carregamento termina mas não é finalizado, não tem a mensagem de sucesso.

Comment: Se apagou a pasta e tentou de novo? ou só desinstalou?

Comment: Apaguei a pasta e tentei de novo várias vezes, além de desinstalar

Comment: @AnaTorres se não está criando os arquivos, pode ser alguma questão de permissão, confira se você possui permissão na pasta para que os arquivos possam ser gerados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso não esteja trabalhando com a versão mais atual do node, recomendo instalar o NVM (Node Version Manager), um gerenciador de versões para o Node, instalar a versão estável mais recente e tentar gerar o create-react-app novamente.

Recomendo esse guia para instalar o NVM: https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/instalando-e-gerenciando-varias-versoes-do-node-js-com-nvm/